# Button doesn't work correct on scene fading

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm facing a problem with scene fading. I made a animation of fade in & out also made a script named as `Fader` which has a coroutine function. Animation works fine. There is also a empty game object named as `SceneManager` which has a script. In this script button functions are written which open a scene.
[image]

[image]

But the problem is when i click any button,for example `Scene2 Button` then fade in animation start,at some `milliseconds` when black screen appear,if i click on this black screen then another scene is open. It won't open `scene2` Watch this video

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1H5fdK2PJAnbm5fWDhlN3dVVnc

package link
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1H5fdK2PJAnZ2Y1UEFRMmVFbTA

Scene Manager script:

```
public class Manager : MonoBehaviour
{

    public void GoBackScene1 ()
    {
        Fader.instance.Perform ("Scene1");

    }

    public void Scene2 ()
    {
        Fader.instance.Perform ("Scene2");
    }

    public void Scene3 ()
    {

        Fader.instance.Perform ("Scene3");
    }

    public void Scene4 ()
    {
        Fader.instance.Perform ("Scene4");

    }


}
```

Scene Fader Script:

```
public class Fader : MonoBehaviour {

    public static Fader instance;

    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject canvas;

    [SerializeField]
    private Animator anim;


    void Awake(){

        makeSingleton ();
    }


    public void Perform(string levelname)
    {
        StartCoroutine(FadeInAnimation(levelname));


    }

    void makeSingleton(){

        if (instance != null) {

            Destroy (gameObject);
        } else {
            instance = this;
            DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);

        }



    }

    IEnumerator FadeInAnimation(string level){

        canvas.SetActive (true);

        anim.Play ("FadeIn");

        yield return new WaitForSeconds (1f);

        Application.LoadLevel (level);

        anim.Play ("FadeOut");

        yield return new WaitForSeconds (2f);

        canvas.SetActive (false);


    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the thing:

Fade in animation length is 0.417 seconds. Between the start of animation and LoadLevel, you wait for 1 second. That means the screen stays black for 0.583 seconds.

The problem is that during all this time, all other buttons are clickable. So if you click "Scene 2", then click the black screen, you can accidentally hit "Scene 3" button, which will initiate `FadeInAnimation("Scene3")`. Since you made `Fader` non-destroyable singleton, level load will not stop `FadeInAnimation("Scene3")` execution.

What you need is some locking, to prevent clicking other buttons while screen is black. For example, something like this will do the job:

```
private bool fading = false;

IEnumerator FadeInAnimation(string level){

    if (fading) yield break;
    fading = true;

    canvas.SetActive (true);

    anim.Play ("FadeIn");

    yield return new WaitForSeconds (1f);

    Application.LoadLevel (level);

    anim.Play ("FadeOut");

    yield return new WaitForSeconds (2f);

    canvas.SetActive (false);

    fading = false;

}
```

Comment: can you suggest me what seconds are write in  `yield return new WaitForSeconds (1f)` for fade in and out

Comment: There is no right or wrong amount of seconds, you decide. Actually using a hardcoded value is the wrong choice, the waiting time should be based on your animation length.

Comment: As fafase said, there is no right or wrong here, you can leave it 1 second, it is Ok, but try not to miss the point of the problem: the problem occurs not because of animation length, it is because you don't disable your buttons during the animation.

Comment: @fafase is there any proper solution you can suggest

Comment: Summing up the last two comments you could understand that you need to disable your button and use the length of the animation as waiting time (while animation is running, it waits) so that if you need more time, you decrease the animation speed and if you need less time, you increase the animation speed (or extend/reduce the animation length). This way your animation always lands right on time.